# Remove empty stdclass object from array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, object, stdclass

I have the following example data in PHP:

```
[{"id": 2088996538},{},{"id": 2077495673}]
```

How can I end up with

```
[{"id": 2088996538},{"id": 2077495673}]
```

I've tried several things, like

```
unset($activities[1]);
```

but then I end up with

```
{"0":{"id":2088996538},"2":{"id":2077495673}}
```

It looks like something soo simple, but can't figuring it out.

The ultimate goal is to clean up some strava api output, deleting everything I don't use.

Edit:

```
$activities = json_decode('[{"id": 2088996538},{},{"id": 2077495673}]');
unset($activities[1]);
$activities = array_values($activities);
echo json_encode($activities);
```

this actually works, how could I've missed it. Gonna try it out with the larger data set. Thanks!

Comment: _"I've tried several things"_ - Show us your attempt and we can help you from there.

Comment: you're right: I was just editing my attempts :)

Comment: That can't be your complete attempt. That's just a single `unset()`. Show us _all_ the relevant code or we won't know the context (and don't add it as a snippet).

Comment: @AbraCadaver how is it fine?

Comment: JS / JSON doesn't have non-sequential arrays, so they have to export to an object. So the "solution" when using unset is to reset the keys to be sequential (from 0), using e.g. `array_values`.

Comment: The result can simply be fixed (so it becomes an array again) using `$activities = array_values($activities);` before json encoding it again.

Comment: I'm actually using a much bigger array, but pointed it down to the fact that I'm not able to delete a specific empty object in this array.

Comment: @JonStirling there is nothing in the question about JS. JSON !============ JS

Comment: Fair point. Fixed.

Comment: Sequential indexes are rarely needed, why does it matter???

Comment: Well, if OP wants a JSON array, rather than an object, then...

Comment: I would recommend that you check out the answers you got below since they are scaleable compared to manually unsetting the array items.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson, thanks. Sorry for polluting the thread. I've added a new answer but I'm not sure if I had better edited my original post...

Comment: Not sure why you didn't just use one of the answer you got and accepted that instead of writing your own? They seem a bit cleaner and easier.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson hm yes, I've come to the conclusion that I could've better started with my own answer below. I need to check for a null value (I ended up somewhere with an empty object, so thought that had to be asked), and if null remove that item

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can filter out the empty objects.

```
$data = array_values(array_filter($data, function($item) {
    return (bool) (array) $item;
}));
```

`array_values` is necessary to prevent the `{"0":{"id":2088996538},"2":{"id":2077495673}}` form you were getting, because it reindexes the array.

The intermediate cast to array in the callback is necessary because any object evaluates to true whether it's empty or not, but an empty array will evaluate to false. If you decode to arrays instead of objects by setting the second parameter of `json_decode` to true, that cast isn't necessary.

---

Not directly related to the original question, but here's my suggestion for another way to do this starting with the data from the API:

```
$activities = json_decode($json, true);

$set_keys = array_flip(["start_latlng", "id", "start_date","name"]);

foreach ($activities as $activity) {
    if (!is_null($activity['start_latlng'])) {
        $result[] = array_intersect_key($activity, $set_keys);
    }
}

echo json_encode($result);
```

Comment: Wow awesome, only few lines of code and works like a charm! thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you decode to arrays using the second argument, then filtering is easier:

```
$activities = json_decode('[{"id": 2088996538},{},{"id": 2077495673}]', true);
$activities = array_values(array_filter($activities));
```

But you still need to re-index if you want sequential indexes.

Comment: hope he doesn't need some `{foo:false}` or `{foo:0}` or `{foo:''}` value, but yeah